# Custom class type in Server-side ActionScript in Flash Media Server 4

Tags: flash, actionscript, ssas, flash-media-server

**How would one create custom class in Flash Media Server 4 in asc code file?**

I can redefine custom methods on present objects, like Client here:

```
Client.prototype.echo = function (complexType /*ComplexType*/) {
    trace("Client.echo > calling echo");        
    application.broadcastMsg("echoCallback", complexType);
}
```

But I don't know how to define custom class.. is that even possible?

I need to know this, so I can properly relay object from client to other client and don't loose class type (see question [How to relay complex type via NetConnection to FMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082433/how-to-relay-complex-type-via-netconnection-to-fms))

EDIT1: I have solved my problem with relaying client-server-client complex types, but still the question stands:

**If and how can I create custom class definition in Server-side ActionScript?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. ServerSide Actionscript is JavaScript 1.5 in fact. Just read about OOP in JavaScript.

You can define classes the following way

```
SomeClass = function()
{
    this.someProperty = 5;
    this.anotherProperty = "Hello";
}
```

Then you create class instances

```
var inst = new SomeClass()
trace(inst.someProperty); //"5"
trace(inst.anotherProperty); //"Hello"
```

Comment: I was looking it all wrong, if I knew, that class is just a function for SSAS... Thx. [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)